# How can use our OAuth server authentication using resource owner password flow?

Tags: expo

I have a OAuth server for authorization, I want to authenticate user using 'resource owner password flow' in react native expo .... how can I do that ?

for instance, I provide user name password, issuer, scope and client I'd and it authenticate it by hitting my server.

I have used AppAuth for android but its not fulfilling my requirement. Any suggestions???